# Open a Modal from Another Modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to Open a modal from a link in another modal in ng-bootstrap.

Once the modal is closed with `NgbActiveModal.close` I can't manage to open the other modal.

The structure is similar to this one:

```
<header>
    <modal1 #firstModal></modal1>
    <modal2 #secondModal></modal2>
</header>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xHzX6SFu30WrKCUHRYV?p=preview)

Comment: Hello. SO is not a place to make us do the job. You should show some effort and tell us what you have tried and where you have failed. And DEFINITELY NOT ask us for a plunker!

Comment: I understand, even tho the part with "us" is not relevant. Some people prefer to explain in a plnkr. I don't want anyone to do the job for me.

Comment: That's okay, the question just was phrased in a way that triggered me a bit "can anyone help with a plunker". You could make a plunker and let other play around with it ;) But no worries man, didn't mean to be so harsh, sorry.

Comment: I have updated with a basic plunkr with a link that should be opening the second modal. It is hard to replicate exactly my setup, so this is as basic as possible.

Comment: Yes I saw, that's why you got an upvote from me ;) But yeah, enough chitchat, or we get flagged for that :D

Comment: Quite confused what you are trying to do with the plunkr, Your <a href="">Open Modal 2</a> is not doing anything its not calling open(modal2). Am I missing something?

Comment: I am trying to replicate the problem. Basically, if I knew what to do, I wouldn't ask the question. If I do all the things that I tried - eventEmitter and services, it will only break the plnkr.

Comment: If you change your <a href="">Open Modal 2</a> to <a href="#" (click)="open(modal2)">Open Modal 2</a>, it will open a new modal. It doesn't however closes the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you want.
Based on my understanding on what you want to achieve is to close modal 1 and open modal 2.

Your Open Modal 2 needs to be changed to:

```
<a href="#" (click)=" d('dismiss modal1'); open(modal2);">Open Modal 2</a>
```

See the changes on plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/T7VOmZ7KWdqjTtYb8Wzd

Comment: This is what I want, I will accept your answer. Do you know how can I do that if the components are siblings, like the example in the question?

Comment: I am unable to achieve that, it is unable to find #modal2. Probably due to the way how ngBootstrap generates it.